# Drop Table doesnot result on deleting data in the sqlite file

Tags: sqlite

I have a `Sqlite` database file that i modify it by dropping a huge database table that contains thousands of records but the file size remains as it before dropping the table. it seems that it disconnect  pointers to data . any ideas how to drop table and make a deep deletion of it in the underlying sqlite file .??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reclaim space, use the `vacuum` statement.

From a sqlite prompt

```
sqlite> VACUUM;
```

From a shell prompt.

```
$ sqlite3 filename 'VACUUM;'
```